# No Soundcards found. Alsa disappeared?

Tags: sound, alsa, soundcard, hda-intel

My sound has disappeared on my Ubuntu Lucid machine.  It was there yesterday.  I think we took a power cycle overnight and so my pc had rebooted this morning.  After compiling PJSUA (the pjsip commandline sip client) and installing  it, I tried to run it.  No sound.

```
$ lsmod | grep snd
```

no output.

```
$ alsamixer
No such file or directory,
```

Just because you need to know, I tried innstalling oss on this machine.  Did n't get it working and TTHOUGHT i'd remove it.  But some parts are still there.

I have googled for hours and have tried a dozen fixes.  None have worked.

```
$ sudo lshw
      .......
        *-multimedia UNCLAIMED
         description: Audio device
         product: 631xESB/632xESB High Definition Audio Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1b
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
         version: 09
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: memory:fcffc000-fcffffff
      .......

$ lspci
      .......
      00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 631xESB/632xESB High Definition Audio Controller (rev 09)
      .......

$ sudo apt-get remove alsa-utils
$ sudo apt-get install alsa-utils

$ sudo apt-get remove alsa-base
$ sudo apt-get install alsa-base

$ sudo apt-get remove pulseaudio

$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install linux-alsa-driver-modules-$(uname -r)

$ sudo echo options snd-hda-intel model=generic >> /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
$ sudo echo snd-hda-intel >> /etc/modules
```

and probably others I've forgotten.

Root also does not see the soundcards.  Of course this is Ubuntu so I can't just login from scratch as root.

I read a suggestion that I might have accidentally blacklisted the snd modules, but I'm not sure which blacklist that'd be in and how to un-blacklist them.

Any help?  Anyone?

Comment: What happens when you run `modprobe snd-hda-intel`?

Comment: $ modprobe snd-hda-intel
    FATAL: Module snd_hda_intel not found.
Does not sound promising does it?

Comment: Additional news:   I rebooted and GRUB-selected my previous kernel.  Sound works just fine.  "modprobe snd-hda-intel" returns nothing.  Knowing this, should I just apt-get a new kernel upgrade and clobber the previous kernel upgrade?  Perhaps I should delete the last kernel upgrade?  By deleting what?

Answer (score 1):

The sound driver is not included in your kernel, or not installed, or got deleted by another sound system.

(Re)installing the kernel should help.

Comment: Should I remove the latest kernel (2.6.32-44-generic) before reinstalling?  Or just install over it?  I am running kernel (latest - 1), (2.6.32-43-generic).   All I need to do is to delete the "2.6.32-44" files in /root and do a grub-update, right?

Comment: The install should detect missing files.